# Find child of a LinearLayout inside a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, childviews

I have a LinearLayout ("ll") that is already created in xml and the app dynamically creates another LinearLayout inside of it and creates an EditText and a Button inside of that view. The button makes the whole LinearLayout destroy itself along with the EditText and Button inside it (the whole system is a player name entering activity). Anyway, I am trying to find a way to get the text from all of the EditTexts. I have tried using a for loop on "ll" and using `ll.getChildAt()` but I can't seem to use `.getChildAt()` on whatever `ll.getChildAt()` generates because `getChildAt()` generates a "View" not a "LinearLayout." I basically just need a way to search two children in, rather than just one. Also, if there is just a better way I should be doing this, let me know. I'm open to suggestions.

Here's my code if it will help:

**NewGameCreate.java**

```
public class NewGameCreate extends Activity {

int numOfPlayers = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_game_create);
}

public void newPlayer(View view) {
    numOfPlayers++;
    final LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.playerView);
    final LinearLayout llNew = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    llNew.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    llNew.setId(numOfPlayers);
    ll.addView(llNew);

    EditText newName = new EditText(this);
    newName.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
    newName.setHint("Enter Player Name");
    newName.setId(numOfPlayers);
    newName.setWidth(0);
    llNew.addView(newName);

    final Button delete = new Button(this);
    delete.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0));
    delete.setText("Delete");
    delete.setId(numOfPlayers);
    delete.setWidth(0);
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = delete.getId();
            ll.removeViewInLayout(findViewById(id));
            Drawable back = ll.getBackground();
            ll.setBackgroundColor(00000000);
            ll.setBackground(back);
            ll.invalidate();
        }
    });
    llNew.addView(delete);
}

public void startGame(View view){
    LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.playerView);
    List text = new ArrayList();

    for(int loop = 0; loop < ll.getChildCount(); loop++) {
        //this is the code in question and where I want to get the text from
        //all my EditTexts
        LinearLayout inner = ll.getChildAt(loop);


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer to it. You need to change a little bit of code in the startGame() method I m providing the code for startGame below.

```
   public void startGame(View view) {
        LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.playerView);
        List text = new ArrayList();

        for (int loop = 0; loop < ll.getChildCount(); loop++) {
            //this is the code in question and where I want to get the text from
            //all my EditTexts
            LinearLayout inner = (LinearLayout) ll.getChildAt(loop);
            for (int j = 0; j < inner.getChildCount(); j++) {
                if (inner.getChildAt(j) instanceof EditText) {
                    EditText textET = (EditText) inner.getChildAt(j);

                    Log.d("TAG",textET.getText().toString());
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

In the above code you were able to get the first child only but as you have added a linearLayout with orientation Horizontal in a parent LinearLayout with orientation Vertical, you have written code for the child of parent layout i.e playerView. I have modified the code to get the elements of the child Linear layout and Log prints all the text from the EditText.

Hope that helps!!

Comment: So basically I just had to add `(LinearLayout)` in front of the `.getChildAt()`. Thank you for the help! This works :)

Comment: Great Happy to help!